# get-aduser - output specific properties dynamically

Tags: powershell

Some specified properties should be written to shell. Hardcoded workaround is one line per property:

```
echo (get-aduser $user -property name).name
```

Outputs:

```
Name.User
```

But I need some dynamic. Why it doesn't work with variables:

```
$attr=("name","CanonicalName")
for($i=0;$i -lt $arr.length;$i++){
    echo (get-aduser $user -property $attr[$i]).$attr[$i]
}
```

I need to output only the properties contained in attributes array. I never used posh before and sitting on this for quite some days and be open to any other way to obtain a list of the requested properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` index operator at the very end is not applied until *after* the predecing expression has resolved:

```
(get-aduser $user -property $attr[$i]).$attr[$i]
# is evaluated as
((get-aduser $user -property $attr[$i]).$attr)[$i]
```

Change it to:

```
(get-aduser $user -property $attr[$i]).($attr[$i])
# or 
(get-aduser $user -property $attr[$i])."$($attr[$i])"
```